# Bindding another port on IIS

Tags: iis, https

I have two website on IIS 7

The first website use https port 443, domain abc.xyz.com, content "Hello world!!!"
The second website use https port 9443, domain 123.xyz.com, content "123456789"

When I browse https:// 123.xyz.com:9443, browser show "123456789"
but browse  https:// 123.xyz.com, browser show "Hello world!!!"

I want https:// 123.xyz.com can't browse.

(I add **space** after **https://** because I have < 10post)

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will default to requesting port 443 when it see's that you are using the https:// protocol.

To achieve your goal, I would suggest using something other than 443 for your "Hello World" site and leaving 443 unbound.